# Evaluation order of furrr:future_map

Tags: r

I am using the future_map function from the furrr package and can't find any information on how the order of computations is occuring.

Consider the example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess, workers=20)

data.frame(t=seq(1,100,1)^2) %>%
 mutate(tmp = future_map(.x=t,.f=function(x){sys.sleep(x); return(1)}))
```

***My question is this:*** is the future_map evaluation in sequential order - starting with the first row and ending with the last row, one row at a time? In which case I could rearrange the time consuming iterations in the beginning so as to reduce idle-time of the cores. Or does it cluster the dataframe into 20 pieces and then send them to each worker? In which case a more elaborate rearrangement would be optimal. Or is it happening in a third and different way?

Comment: I can't think of any reason the function would have to kick off the processes in a different order than they appear in the list. If each iteration takes a wildly different amount of time, it would seem to make sense to put the long ones first. Did you try that at all? Did you notice any difference?

Comment: Yes it seems that ordering the long iterations first is better. But that does not exclude that some other arrangement might be better. Say if some grouping of the dataframe is send to each cluster at the beginning. At this point there is nothing in the package documentation that says anything about this matter.

Comment: Since the function is meant to be a drop in replacement for `map` I think it would be safe to assume it basically would start jobs in the same order. There's no way the function could predict exactly how long any code chunk would take so it can't really optimize the execution order. If you think this is just a documentation problem, then you can file an issue with the package maintainer: https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues